# How do I take my variable out of a function? Ive used "return" and tried re-assigning but it doesnt work. I need the value entered to be assign to num

Tags: python, function, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Two Total Triumph")
root.geometry("500x200")

num_var = tk.StringVar()

def submit():
    num = num_var.get()
    num_var.set(" ")
    print("Your number is: " + num + "\nClose tab to continue.")


num_label = tk.Label(root, text='Input number between 3 and 39: ', font=('times new roman', 15, 
'bold'))

num_entry = tk.Entry(root, textvariable=num_var, font=('times new roman', 15, 'normal'))

sub_btn = tk.Button(root, text='Submit', command=submit)

num_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
num_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
sub_btn.grid(row=1, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

In the submit function i assign num to the variable thats entered into my pop-up but I want to keep num assigned to that so i can call it inside a seperate script or at least print it outside the function in this script.

Comment: Where are you going to use it?  The hacky way is to use `global num` inside your `submit` function, so it is stored as a global.  A better way is to turn this into a class, and store it as a class variable.  This is one of the reasons I'd like `tkinter` to die a painful death -- it strongly encourages bad programming practices.

Comment: You can store it as global (actually module-bound) variable with the "global" declaration in the function (described in the docs).

Comment: You can call the function of the other script from `submit()` and pass `num` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

`StringVar`s are mutable containers, which is how they're able to be shared by multiple widgets/functions even though they aren't passed around explicitly.  You could simply declare another one, like this:

```
num_var = tk.StringVar()
last_num = tk.StringVar()

def submit():
    num = num_var.get()
    num_var.set(" ")
    last_num.set(num)
    print("Your number is: " + num + "\nClose tab to continue.")
```

Now `last_num` always holds the most recent value of `num` seen by `submit()`.

Comment: how do i use last_num outside of the function to see what the variable was?

Comment: Just do `last_num.get()`, the exact same way you did `num_var.get()`.